# ignore html tags in jquery slickgrid

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

I have a slickgrid similar to the one from [this](http://www.tutorialsavvy.com/2013/03/jquery-slick-grid-java-integration.html)
example.

The data comes from the database, and in one column I can have values containing html tags, like "font size=... color=.../>", br/> and others (i've written without the first "<", as here the text is automatically formated also).

At runtime, the rows looks very unsightly, as they are formatted respecting to the html tags, so if there are 3 "br"-s, the height of the entire row in slickgrid is increased, also the font is red, etc.
Is there some property for slickgrid to ignore those html tags and dsplaying the text as it is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom formatter to ignore html tags as follows,

```
    function CustomFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
       return $(value).text();
    }
```

For More information try following jquery code,

```
var htmlData= '<div id="xyz">Html Data</div>';
alert($(htmlData).text());
```